# Replacing Hybrid tyre

Tags: tire

I have a bike with mtb tyres size 26*1.95. I am planning to put a smaller hybrid tyre. Is that possible. If so kindly let me know what size would fit. The rim size is 26*1.75.

Comment: The standard answer to all tire size questions: http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html

Comment: Even most MTBs don't have 1.75" rims.

Comment: Are you me? I just purchased 26x1.75 tires for my MTB, to replace the 26x1.95 stock tires. My LBS said it should be close enough.

Answer (score 3):

You can generally go down in tyre width without a problem because frame clearance is not affected.

Going up to larger sizes needs more careful checking, but down is mostly fine.

Do note your rim does not have a "1.75" measurement anywhere.  Its more likely to be 20-25 millimetres in width across where the tyre seats to the rim

One possible risk is decreasing tyre width can expose your rim to damage from potholes and kerbs, but this would be at about half the tyre size, and you're not near that.